# android billing:4.0.0 - purchase.getSku()

Tags: java, android, upgrade, billing

I have a problem using the android billing 4.0.0 version. I have used it before:

```
purchase.getSku()
```

I have this old code to check if it's purchased:

```
PRODUCT_ID.equals(purchase.getSku()) && purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED)
```

I have updated to this code:

`getResources().getString(R.string.Product_ID).equals(purchase.getSkus() .contains(getResources().getString(R.string.Product_ID)) && purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING)`

but after purchase the item nothing in the app change. is it like I have not bought it. 
what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution,
I hope this will help some others.
I have removed

```
getResources().getString(R.string.Product_ID).equals
```

so it will be:

```
purchase.getSkus().contains(getResources().getString(R.string.Product_ID)) && purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED
```